# How to add Delicious post with multiple tags in ruby

Tags: ruby, delicious-api

How can I add a post with more than one tag?

I'm doing this.  The post is added to my Delicious collection but without tags.

> require 'www/delicious'
>
> d_api = WWW::Delicious.new('username', 'password')
>
> d_api.posts_add(:tags=> "tools,ruby,online",:url =>
>   'http://rubular.com/', :title => 'Rubular', :notes=>'a Ruby regular
>   expression editor')

I'm currently using [www/Delicious](http://rubydoc.info/gems/laco-www-delicious/0.3.5/frames) gem but I'm open to other suggestion.

I also try the

> :tags=> ["tools","ruby","online"]

or event use the constructor

> tag = WWW::Delicious::Tag.new(:name => "tools")

but the result is the same the tags are mixted in one[image: Delicious screenshot of the tag]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [Delicious API with HTTParty Gem](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=8955) code I create a class like this

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'httparty'
>
> class Delicious
>   include HTTParty
>   base_uri 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1'
>
>   def initialize(auth)
>     @auth = auth
>   end
>
>   # query params that filter the posts are:
>   #   url      = (required) the url of the item.
>   #   description= (required) the description of the item. 
>   #   extended     = (optional) notes for the item.
>   #   tags         = (optional) tags for the item (comma delimited).
>   #   dt       = {CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ}(optional) datestamp of the item (format "CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ").
>   #   replace  = no(optional) don't replace post if given url has already been posted. 
>   #   shared   = no(optional) make the item private
>   def add(options={}))
>     options.merge!({:basic_auth => @auth})
>     self.class.get('/posts/add', options)
>   end
> end
> ```

Then I can call it like this:

> ```
> delicious = Delicious.new( :username => 'myUsername', :password => 'myPassword' )
> puts delicious.add(:query => {:url => 'http://rubular.com/', :description => 'Rubular', :tags => "tools,ruby,online"})
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API for [WWW::Delicious::Post](http://rubydoc.info/gems/www-delicious/WWW/Delicious/Post), tags are an instance attribute. My guess is that it is an array. Try:

```
d_api.posts_add(:tags=>["tools","ruby","online"],:url => 'http://rubular.com/', :title => 'Rubular', :notes=>'a Ruby regular expression editor')
```

It's possible it's an array of Tag objects, so another thing to try is:

```
my_tags = ["tools","ruby","online"].map {|t| WWW::Delicious::Tag.new(t)}
d_api.posts_add(:tags => my_tags,:url => 'http://rubular.com/', :title => 'Rubular', :notes=>'a Ruby regular expression editor')
```

Comment: That doesn't works as well.  Sorry I forgot that I already try this. I also try to create tag instance with the tag = WWW::Delicious::Tag.new(:name => "tools")

Comment: I added another possibility. Reading the source of the gem will tell you for sure what it is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, what works is this:

```
delicious.posts_add(
  :url   => 'http://www.test2.com',
  :title => 'test',
  :tags => ['test1, test2']
)
```

An array with a single entry being a comma-separated tag list.

Comment: I submit a fix on https://github.com/weppos/www-delicious but still not release.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the Temboo SDK (which comes in Ruby, as well as several other languages) includes methods for the Delicious API in addition to 100+ other public APIs. The AddBookmark method supports multiple tags: just provide a comma-separated list as the input value.

Take a look at https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Delicious/AddBookmark/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Answer (score 0):

I've created [delicious gem](https://github.com/andreychernih/delicious) which is a ruby wrapper for [Delicious oAuth API](https://github.com/SciDevs/delicious-api). You can add a bookmark easily:

```
client = Delicious::Client.new do |c|
  c.access_token = 'your-access-token'
end

client.bookmarks.create tags: 'tools,ruby,online',
                        url: 'http://rubular.com/',
                        description: 'Rubular',
                        extended: 'a Ruby regular expression editor'
```